# use recursive function in python

Tags: python, recursion

I try to use recursive function on python, i have this matrix W:

```
[[ 13.          14.   ]
 [ 12.          15.   ]
 [  0.           4.   ]
 [  3.           6.   ]
 [  7.           8.   ]
 [ 11.          18.   ]
 [ 10.          17.   ]
 [  2.          23.   ]
 [  5.          22.   ]
 [ 16.          19.   ]
 [  1.          27.   ]
 [  9.          21.   ]
 [ 25.          29.   ]
 [ 24.          28.   ]
 [ 20.          26.   ]
 [ 31.          32.   ]
 [ 30.          33.   ]
 [ 34.          35.   ]
 [ 36.          37.   ]]
```

the principle that for each line, I get the values of the two columns, if they are <20 I return them, otherwise I do the modulo until I reach a value lower than 20. for example I have a value 35 which is> 20, so 35% 20 = 15, I go to line 15 I get the value, if I find it for example 11, I return 11, if I find it 23 for example, I redo the modulo 23% 20 = 3, I go to line 3 and so on .. this is my code

```
def modulo(entier):
        if entier < 20:
            return(entier)
        else:
            c = (entier % 20)
            if int(W[c,0]) < 20:
                return(int(W[c,0]))
            else:
                a = modulo(int(W[c,0]))
                return(a)
            if int(W[c,1]) < 20:
                return(int(W[c,1]))
            else:
                e = modulo(int(W[c,1]))
                return(e)
    i = 12
    print(modulo(int(W[i,0])), modulo(int(W[i,1])))
```

here I tried with line 12 of the matrix, which has both values 25 and 29, following the principle the function must return 11 and 18 for the value 25 and 16 and 19 for the value 29. but in the running, the program only displays two values 11 and 16. so I have the impression that it just points to the first column of the matrix, it does not read the second if condition. I hope I explained the problem well and I find a solution. Thank you

Comment: This sound like an iterative process. Why do you want to use recursion?

Comment: @KlausD. It sounds recursive to me, to be honest. But I can’t be sure since the explanation isn’t complete. For instance, what does it mean for two numbers to be < 20? One of them? both? Which one? Also, the argument to the function appears to be a *single* number, not two numbers.

Comment: because I need to do the modulo every time until I reach a value less than 20, as long as it finds a higher value it redo the procedure until it has a value lower than 20. here I am doing a small base of 20 line but after I'm going to apply the same principle with a larger base

Comment: @KonradRudolph I want for each line to apply the same principle for both values (both columns)

Comment: @student, great, post the code where you iterate over the matrix, calling your function and getting he expected result

Comment: for line 12, the first value is 25, 25% 20 = 5 so it will point to line 5 which contains two values 11 and 18 which are less than 20, so it will display it, then it goes to the second column of the same line 12, it contains the value 29, mod 20 = 9, we are in line 9, it contains the 2 values 16 and 19, less than 20 so we also display them. if we find the results greater than 20 we continue the principle

Comment: @KonradRudolph here I did not go through the matrix, I tried for a single line but I did not get the result I want, it just shows me the values of the first column

Comment: i = 12
print(modulo(int(W[i,0])), modulo(int(W[i,1])))

Comment: just here there is a fault, the two lines at the end seem written in the function modulo, while not in my program I wrote them out of this function, so just it's a fault of writing here in the forum